Override a composable in androidTest
I've got a layout hierarchy, that looks like (from top to bottom):
SearchResultScreen
ProductGridView
———————————————— all composables below are handled by a different team
CustomProductTile
InternalProductTile
ProductTileImage
FavouriteButton
The problem is: the favourite button creates it's own view model (with hilt) in the parameters of the composable function (it's not passed from productTileImage)
While writing android tests for the SearchResultScreen I get errors with hilt not being able to instantiate the view model for the favouriteButton, and so my question is:
Is there a better approach than trying to override the CustomProductTile or FavouriteButton to just display an empty box or nothing at all? I've tried the better approaches like:

Using HiltAndroidRule to inject the dependencies and make it run (but it required mocking A LOT of unrelated things that came from modules using this module)
Trying to make the view model manually with a mock (as it's using a repository), but that requires either passing the vm through all composables or lambdas, but that also requires big changes to all the listed composables

Note: I cannot do major changes to all composables below ProductGridView (at least not quickly) and I am aware that the lowest composable in the stack making it's own VM is a crime, but I did not commit it
edit:
I found this lib: https://github.com/jeppeman/mockposable
but I cannot use it

Would it work within your codebase / team structure to create a provider for the composable function which you can then switch out with a simpler or no-op version in your tests?

Can you link / provide an example?

I'll put one in an answer

If you want to be able to swap out composables for tests, one way could be to create a provider interface for the composable which you can then replace with a dummy implementation in your tests.
fun interface CustomProductTileProvider {

    @Composable
    fun CustomProductTile(inputs: Inputs)
}

You can then have an implementation which you provide to hilt:
@Singleton
class CustomProductTileProviderImpl @Inject constructor() : CustomProductTileProvider {

    @Composable
    override fun CustomProductTime(inputs: Inputs) {
        // Your component goes here
    }
}

And in your layout:
@Composable
fun Layout(inputs: Inputs, tileProvider: CustomProductTileProvider) {
    // Search results
    // Product grid
    
    tileProvider.CustomProductTile(inputs)

    // Rest of the layout
}

And then finally in your tests provide this to hilt instead:
class DummyCustomProductTimeProvider : CustomTileProvider {

    @Composable
    override fun CustomProductTile(inputs: Inputs) {
        // No-op or provide some other composable
    }
}

